# How to perfrom `sum` and `avg` aggs in even if the mappings of the field is on `text` and `keyword` types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a `sum` and `avg` aggregations on my Elasticsearch query, everything works perfectly fine but I've encountered a problem -- I want to perform the aforementioned aggs to my `nested` fields that are on `text` / `keyword` types.

The reason that they're as such, is because we'll be using the `keywords` analyzer when we are performing the `search` API if these specific nested field and subfields are required.

Here's my mapping:

```
"eng" : {
  "type" : "nested",
  "properties" : {
    "date_updated" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "soc_angry_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_comment_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_dislike_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_eng_score" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_er_score" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "soc_haha_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_kf_score" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "soc_like_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_love_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_mm_score" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_sad_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_save_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_share_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_te_score" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "soc_view_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "soc_wow_count" : {
      "type" : "float"
    }
  }
}
```

Please focus on the `soc_er_score`, `soc_kf_score` and `soc_te_score` subfields of the `eng` nested field...

When I'm performing the following aggs, it's working fine:

```
'aggs' => [
    'ENGAGEMENT' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => "eng"
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'ARTICLES' => [
                //Use Histogram because the pub_date is of
                //long data type
                //Use interval 86400 to represent 1 day
                'histogram' => [
                    'field'  => "eng.date_updated",
                    "interval" => "86400",
                ],
                'aggs'= [
                    'SUM' => [
                        'sum' => [
                            "field" => "eng.soc_like_score"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here's the output after doing the `search` API

[image]

**BUT** if the query is like this:

```
'aggs' => [
    'ENGAGEMENT' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => "eng"
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'ARTICLES' => [
                //Use Histogram because the pub_date is of
                //long data type
                //Use interval 86400 to represent 1 day
                'histogram' => [
                    'field'  => "eng.date_updated",
                    "interval" => "86400",
                ],
                'aggs'= [
                    'SUM' => [
                        'sum' => [
                            "field" => "eng.soc_te_score"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

**SOLUTIONS PERFORMED**

**SOLUTION 1 (for confirmation)** 
After reading some thorough forum discussions, I've learned that java-based parsing is available but it seems not working on my end

Here's my revised query:

```
'aggs'= [
    'SUM' => [
        'sum' => [
            "field" => "Float.parseFloat(eng.soc_te_score).value"
        ]
    ]
]
```

But unfortunately, it's responding with *null* or **0** `values`

[image]

By the way, I'm using Laravel as my Web Framework, that's why this is how my debugger or error message window look like

Requesting for your help please, thank you in advance!

Comment: I would create another numeric subfield in addition to the keyword one. So you can use the keyword field for search and the numeric one for aggregations.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion sir Val! However, we already got 40 million documents for this index, so the former 40 million documents won't be affected by the new field :(

Comment: See my updated answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another numeric subfield in addition to the keyword one. So you can use the keyword field for search and the numeric one for aggregations.

For example, modify your mapping like this:

```
"soc_er_score" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    },
    "numeric" : {
      "type" : "long",
      "ignore_malformed": true
    }
  }
},
```

You can then use:

- `soc_er_score` for full text search
- `soc_er_score.keyword` for sorting, terms aggregations and exact matching
- `soc_er_score.numeric` for `sum` and other metric aggregations.

If you already have data in your index, simply modify the mapping by adding the new sub-field, like this:

```
PUT my-index/_mapping/doc
{
  "properties": {
    "eng": {
      "soc_er_score" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          },
          "numeric" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "ignore_malformed": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then call the [update by query endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) in order to pick up the new mapping:

```
POST my-index/_update_by_query
```

When done, the `eng.soc_er_score.numeric` field will be indexed for all your existing documents.

Comment: thank you for the wonderful suggestion sir Val! But the downside is, we already have former 40 million documents, and elacticsearch's behavior is that, new fields won't be felt by the old documents/data. I get your idea to create a new field -- it really makes sense, but is there any other way to not create a new field anymore for this? :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with the following simple script:

```
"aggs" = [
    'SUM' => [
        'sum' => [
            "script" => "Float.parseFloat(doc['eng.soc_te_score.keyword'].value)"
        ]
    ]
];
```

With this, even if my nested field is of `text` and `keyword` type, I can still compute for their *average* and *sum*

Comment: Yes, though, you need to be aware that using script in aggregations is not performant at all depending on the size of your document set. I really recommend the other approach instead if you want your solution to be future proof and optimal. Using scripting is ok for exploratory purposes when trying to figure out the best mapping in an initial phase, or to fix existing data, but I'd discourage you from relying on that in production settings...