# While doing histogram on a nested field, how to get the last value?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is in relation to my previous question:

[How to perfrom `sum` and `avg` aggs in even if the mappings of the field is on `text` and `keyword` types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195921/how-to-perfrom-sum-and-avg-aggs-in-even-if-the-mappings-of-the-field-is-on)

**Process** 
I'm currently formulating an Elasticsearch query that will get all my documents that are based on a range **EVERY DAY**, but the field I'm working on is a `nested` one. So visualize it like I'm counting the total number of documents EVERY DAY according to my range

**Reproducing the scenario**

Date Range: September 15 - September 17

September 15: Found 1000 documents 
September 16: Found 500 documents 
September 17: Found 1500 documents

Here's my sample query:

```
'aggs' => [
    'ENGAGEMENT' => [
        'nested' => [
            'path' => "eng"
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'ARTICLES' => [
                //Use Histogram because the pub_date is of
                //long data type
                //Use interval 86400 to represent 1 day
                'histogram' => [
                    'field'  => "eng.date_updated",
                    "interval" => "86400",
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Here's an example Elasticsearch document that I have:

[image]

With the given scenario and example above, the current query displays this output

[image]

**My main goal** 
With the laid out ideas, how can I retrieve the **last** object of a nested field for each day?

For example:

For September 15, I want to retrieve the **LAST** soc_like_count for that day 
For September 16, I also want to retrieve the **LAST** soc_like_count for that day, and so on...

**TRIED SOLUTIONS**

Was trying to do experiments with the `inner_hits` but after reading for a while, `inner_hits` is only available on the `body` part of the ES query

Is there any way to perform this with an elasticsearch query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub aggregation

```
  "aggs": {
    "date": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "eng.date_updated",
        "interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits": {    ---> added as sub aggregation to date_histogram
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
                        {
                        "date": {   ---> replace by field name you want to sort
                                    "order": "desc"
                              }
                      }
             ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```