# Elastic search 6.2 group by query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

**elastic search version:** 6.2

I want the count data group by a particular field

**example**:

*Assume I have 3 following docs*

{
field1: "value1"
}
{
field1: "value2"
}
{
field1: "value2"
}

*I want the following result*

value1: 1

value2: 2

**Note**: Field is of type text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Val, there is one issue in this approach, let say the field value is "abc xyz", so it is considering "abc" and xyz differently. Any suggestions?

Comment: actually, it's a text field, that will be the reason mostly. Any workaround for the text field?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to create a subfield of type keyword

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/text.html#before-enabling-fielddata @LakhanJain

Comment: @cmhteixeira fielddata is no good. Better use keyword instead

Comment: Agree. The link actually contains the mappings for the subfield with `keyword` type for @LakhanJain to do just that . :)

Comment: @LakhanJain you can proceed as in the following thread to add a `keyword` subfield: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195999/4604579 or use the link shared by @cmhteixeira

Comment: @Val What can be the potential drawback of adding a subfield?

Comment: None really... except increasing a little bit the space it takes on disk. if you don't need the `text` field you can also decide to only have a `keyword` field.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called aggregations. Here is the query:

```json
GET /yourIndex/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "myCustomAggregation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note however that you cannot perform aggregations on fields (in your case field `field1`) which are `text` fields. You should set that field as `keyword`.